# JQuery Autocomplete для 2-х зависимых input'ов

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Суть такова: у меня есть два input'а(input1 и input2). К input1 подвязан JQuery Autocomplete, данные подгружаются из JSON, всё работает и проблем нет. Код:

```
var data = [];

$.getJSON('путь_к_файлу', function(result) {
  $.each(result.entries,function(index,val) {
    data.push(val);
  });
});

$(function(){
  $("#id").autocomplete ({
  source: data,
  minLength: 3
})

  .focus(function() {
      $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
  });
});
```

JSON имеет вид:

```
{
   "entries": [
       {"label":"text1"},
       {"label":"text2"},
       {"label":"text3"}
   ]
}
```

Не получается сделать так, чтобы в input2 подгружался другой JSON с данными, тоже с Autocomplet'ом, если значение в input1 будет конкретным, например, только text2?
Т.е. если input1 = text2, то к input2 подключаем JSON2 c Autocomplet'ом, а если input1 != text2, то ничего не подключаем и пусть пользователь заводит руками)

Пробовал еще делать вот так, данные Autocomplete в input2 не подгружаются и срабатывают на любое значение в input1, а нужно только на конкретное:

```
var data = [];
    $.getJSON('путь_к_файлу', function(result) {
        $.each(result.entries, function(index, val) {
            data.push(val);
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $("input1").autocomplete({
                source: data,
                minLength: 3,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("input2").autocomplete({
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "путь_к_файлу",
                                dataType: "jsonp",
                                data: {
                                    term: ui.item.value
                                },
                                success: function(data) {
                                    response(data);
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        minLength: 3
                    });
                }
            })
            .focus(function() {
                $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
            });
    });
```